# MySQL/Python -> Wrong Syntax for Placeholder in Statements?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, insert, placeholder

I am trying to use placeholder in an insert-statement.

I am using PyCharm/Python 3.6, a MySQL-Database, and the mysql.connector (don't know which of them exactly.)

[image]

Why doesn't the following code work?

```
insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO mydb.datensatz (Titel) VALUES ('%s');"
data = (titel)
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
cnx.commit()
```

titel is a string.

This is what gets inserted, but I need to have the titel-string into that row.
[image]

When deleting the '  ' in the values-braces, PyCharm gives me an error with incorrect MySQL-syntax.

How to use placeholders in this case? How could I use more placeholders for example at inserting into more columns than one? Research didn't help.

Comment: I haven't done much more than play around with python a bit when it was new; but would parenthesis around the query string itself as shown in the official example [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) make a difference?

Comment: @Uueerdo Sadly it makes no difference, as it still inserts %s into that specific row.

Comment: According to the example you should not be be putting `'`'s around the `%s`... I just looked up PyCharm, is it just an IDE "intellisense-style error", or does it actually refuse to run the query?

Comment: @Uueerdo Without those quotes, it gives me an SQL-Syntax-Error, so they are needed I suppose :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes from the `%s` AND make sure your parameters are a in a tuple:

```
insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO mydb.datensatz (Titel) VALUES (%s);" # Removed quotes around %s
data = (titel,) # Added trailing comma to make tuple
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
cnx.commit()
```

When you have a single value in a tuple, you must include a trailing comma: `(item,)`