# MySQL/Python connector not being able to search

Tags: python, mysql, database

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '*******',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database': 'mydb',
    'raise_on_warnings': True
}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

find_user = ("SELECT * FROM HM_Login WHERE Username = '%s' ")
data_Pupil = {
    'Username': "GJM"
}
cursor.execute(find_user, data_Pupil)

lit = cursor.fetchall()
print(lit)
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

I have a database that works and i am having a problem trying to search the database and pull one row of one column when i was inserting into the database the %S worked just fine but now it only works if i have a value inside the the query. this is using the mysql connector for python.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I am getting this error which is extremely insightful and not helpful at all if there is anything you can do to help it would mean a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error statement says. You have an SQL error. You are trying to input a variable as a positional parameter but you've used a dictionary on a variables 'place'.

Instead you should use %s for variables and tuples with variables and then do the following:

```
find_user = "SELECT * FROM HM_Login WHERE Username = %s"
data_Pupil = ('GJM',)
cursor.execute(find_user, data_Pupil)
```

It is also possible to use dictionary - but you shouldn't. Despite that I'm still going to show it here as I had to dig into the explanation to understand why.

```
find_user = "SELECT * FROM HM_Login WHERE Username = '{Username}'".format(**data_Pupil)
data_Pupil = {
    'Username': "GJM"
    }
```

The above opens up for sql-injections, as I was told per the comments - and here is why; Say we have a username that is identical to the following:

```
username = "'MR SQL Injection');DROP TABLE HM_Login;"
```

That would result in an SQL Query that drops the table.

```
SELECT * FROM HM_Login WHERE Username = 'MR SQL Injection');DROP TABLE HM_Login;
```

To avoid sql-injection as above. Use the first solution

Comment: that has worked thank you very much

Comment: Even though they look similar, MySQL statement placeholders and Python string `format` are nowhere near interchangeable.

Comment: @Zach Don't use this, you're opening yourself up to SQL injection!

Comment: then how do i fix this in a way that works as ? does not work with what i am doing

Comment: @Zach https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927569/476

Comment: @deceze - would you care to explain a little further. I guess you are the one downvoting - so maybe a clarification might be in order?

Comment: Simply using `"...".format(...)` does not prevent SQL injection. You're just doing string interpolation, which is exactly how SQL injection issues happen. And the first suggestions is not using MySQL placeholders correctly either (see linked answer above).

Comment: well thank you for the help

Comment: I've added further explanation to my answer. Thank you for raising the point @deceze

Comment: I don't think `?` is supported as a placeholder: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your placeholder syntax is for positional parameters but you've used a dictionary. Replace that with a tuple:

```
find_user = ("SELECT * FROM HM_Login WHERE Username = %s")
data_pupil = ('GJM',)
cursor.execute(find_user, data_Pupil)
```

Comment: i then get this error ?   mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GJM''' at line 1

Comment: You shouldn't surround your placeholder with quotes, the whole point of placeholders is that they do that for you. Updated answer with full code.